# Retrieve records in rails by weekday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I want to show a chart that shows on which day certain records are created (e.g. Monday 5 records, Tuesday 2 records, etc.)

How can I retrieve records by weekday in rails?

Thanks in advance
Mike.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-day) what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group` on your ActiveRecord query to group by the weekday. Something similar to below:

```
def self.recent_by_day(created_after
  where("create_at >= ?", created_after).group("day")
end
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it like this

```
MyClass.where("DAYOFWEEK(created_at) == 3")
```

In your case if you want all the values for a graph you can do this:

```
MyClass.select("DAYOFWEEK(created_at) as DOW, count(*) as CNT")
       .group("DOW").each do |f| 
    puts "#{f.DOW}, #{f.CNT}" 
end
```

Output:

```
1, 2
5, 1
7, 68
```

I think in this case it is better to use the power of the database to handle the grunt work of grouping.  That's what they are good at.

Comment: Thanks John,I think this works for MySQL, but I'm working with Postgres. I found some documentation on DOW, but I can't seem to make it work. Any thoughts? Thanks